# how to handle the fragment state when dialog dismissed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a `ListView` in a `Dialog`. When I select an item from the the list I dismiss the `Dialog`. Now the previous `Fragment` appears. I need to get the selected value from the `Dialog`.

```
addressListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
        addr = (Address) addressListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        AppUtils.printLog("selected",addr.getLatitude()+","+addr.getLongitude());
        dismiss();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a listener to your `Dialog`. For example add something like this to you `Dialog` class:

```
private AddressListener addressListener;
public interface AddressListener {
    public void onSelected(Address address);
}

public AddressListener getAddressListener() {
    return addressListener;
}

public void setAddressListener(AddressListener addressListener) {
    this.addressListener = addressListener;
}
```

I recommend you also write a helper method to notify the listener:

```
protected void notifyAddressListener(Address address) {
    if(this.addressListener != null) {
        this.addressListener.onSelected(address);
    }
}
```

You then just have to call `notifyAddressListener(...)` in the `OnItemClickListener` to pass a value back to the listener:

```
addressListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
        addr = (Address) addressListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        AppUtils.printLog("selected",addr.getLatitude()+","+addr.getLongitude());

        // Notify listener
        notifyAddressListener(addr);

        dismiss();
    }
});
```

In your `Fragment` or `Activity` or wherever you create and show the `Dialog` you have to set the `AddressListener` like this:

```
ExampleDialog dialog = new ExampleDialog();
dialog.setAddressListener(this);
dialog.show();
```

Of course you then have to implement the `onSelected()` method in your `Fragment` or `Activity` and as soon as the user picks an item in the `Dialog` `onSelected()` will be called.

Comment: ..I think you did't get my point. I save address in static variable. now dialog dismiss and I have save the value. previous fragment appears. what is the state of previous fragment. i mean is there onresume call or something else???

Comment: First of all: Don't save it in a static variable. That is terrible design and will only cause problems, use a listener like I describe in my answer. And yes of course there is an `onResume()` call. The `Fragment` goes through it's normal lifecycle. [Link to documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating).

Comment: I am working on for long time. `onResume` is not called. what is the problem??

Comment: Well I don't magically know what the problem is if you don't give me any information. What do you want to do in `onResume()` in the first place?